# "I don't hear you clearly" vs. "I'm not hearing you clearly" in context

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple

Would you please tell me if there is any difference in meaning between *I don't hear you clearly* and *I'm not hearing you clearly* in the context below?

> Would you please speak into the phone as **I don't hear you** clearly.
>
> Would you please speak into the phone as **I'm not hearing you** clearly.

Are both perfectly natural there? If so, is there any difference in meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*I don't hear you clearly*" seems wrong in this context.

'Don't' normally refers to what *never* happens, or what *should* never happen - for example, "*I don't eat meat*", or "*I don't speak Spanish*".

When something may be possible, but is not *currently* possible for some reason, we would normally say "*I can't*" (a contraction of '*I cannot*').

So, saying "*I can't hear you clearly*" suggests that you are trying to hear but, for some reason, you are unable to.

Your alternative of "*I'm not hearing you clearly*" is fine, as the present continuous tense indicates this is a *current* issue.

Answer (score 0):

They are both correct, but the first would be less usual in most locations.

*"Would you please speak into the phone as I **can't** hear you clearly."* would probably be most natural in most places.

Comment: Less usual in most locations? That is simply not the case. Sorry.

Comment: No need to be sorry, but some backup would be useful.  (I researched using Google).

Comment: Yes, research using google can be *useful* but an informed native speaker should beat it most of the time. That's the "back-up".

Comment: Right. And I am a native user, and, in this case, I fully agree with Google. Have you got anything to support your assertion?

Comment: A native user? Whoops. :)

Comment: It is not idiomatic to say, *I don't hear you,* to mean, *I can't hear you.*  I think you can find the roots of the issue in the verbs *do* and *can*.  *I cannot hear you,* implies I am trying to hear what you are saying but something is preventing me from hearing you.  *I do not hear you,* means you are trying to communicate with me but **you** are failing.  *When you start talking about the conquests of Rasputin, I do not hear you*  (because I do not listen to talk of Rasputin.)

Answer (score 0):

Samples:

Would you please speak into the phone as I don't hear you clearly.

Would you please speak into the phone as I'm not hearing you clearly.

1. Generally, it would be "more natural" to say "I *can't* hear you clearly".

hear is a sense verb, like feel or look or seem.

2. **They are usually used in the simple present.**

This coat feels good.
The soup tastes good.
The weather looks awful.

However:

For something happening at the moment or for a voluntary action, the present continuous can be used:

I'm not hearing you clearly. [like the example above]
That's not sounding very good. [what someone says]

Here's a chart that sums up the uses of these types of verbs, which I cannot reproduce here. Please click the link:

[sense verbs](https://test-english.com/explanation/b2/verbs-of-the-senses/#:%7E:text=The%20verbs%20feel%2C%20look%2C%20smell,when%20they%20are%20voluntary%20actions.&text=We%20can%20also%20use%20feel,m%20not%20feeling%20very%20well.)

There are also a few verbs that change meaning in the simple present and continuous: hear and see, for example.

[sense verbs](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/sense-verbs/#:%7E:text=A%20sense%20verb%20is%20a,are%20sensory%20(sense)%20verbs.)